# Is ConfigureAwait(false) mainly for the back-boundary?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

Edited Note: Do not read my question and previous understanding as being correct, the answer(s) clear up where my misconceptions were.

Given this Call Stack of async methods:

```
InterfaceMethod > InternalPublicMethod > InternalPrivateMethod > HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()
```

And given my understanding of `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which means the call to said configured async method should be irrespective of the SynchronizationContext (Shouldn't try to marshall back).

If my first InterfacedMethod calls `await InternalPublicMethod().ConfigureAwait(false)`, then InternalPublicMethod runs irrespective of the Context, right?  So when it calls `InternalPrivate`, which then calls `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()`, aren't those also run irrespective the context?  I don't want to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to "Be Safe".  I want to do what is necessary and correct.  I don't believe the SynchronizationContext re-attaches to the async stack after a prior call in the stack has done `ConfigureAwait(false)`

Second Question: If a consumer of my library calls one of my Interfaced Methods, do they have to call `ConfigureAwait(false)`?  If you don't know or don't trust a third party library, you may find it best to do so, to "Be Safe".  But if this is a library I'm consuming and I know that all of its interfaced methods and internal code use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, I shouldn't have to when calling them, right?

Not to say my consuming code would never use `ConfigureAwait(false)` wherever else is necessary, but it shouldn't be necessary there if I understand it correctly.

I am currently not having any issues with the way I'm doing it, I just want to be responsible in this library I have published.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> then InternalPublicMethod runs irrespective of the Context, right?

No.  You're configuring *the await*, not the method being called.  `InternalPublicMethod` runs on the current synchronization context.  It's the code that runs after awaiting it that *might* no longer be running on the current sync context.

> I don't believe the SynchronizationContext re-attaches to the async stack after a prior call in the stack has done ConfigureAwait(false)

You're *only* affecting the continuation in the current method.  You're not affecting things above or below you in the call stack here.  `await` calls above you in the call stack may have themselves captured the call stack and may use it for their continuations.  Continuations created in `InternalPublicMethod` may capture the call stack and use it for their continuations.  You're *only* affecting the current method's code running after the `await`.

> If a consumer of my library calls one of my Interfaced Methods, do they have to call ConfigureAwait(false)

That depends entirely on what the caller is doing, and whether the caller wants their continuation to use the current sync context, which you shouldn't care about at all, as a library author.  There should be situations where it is warranted, and situations where it's not.

> If you don't know or don't trust a third party library, you may find it best to do so, to "Be Safe". But if this is a library I'm consuming and I know that all of its interfaced methods and internal code use ConfigureAwait(false), I shouldn't have to when calling them, right?

Since it doesn't affect the method you call, but rather the code runs after the returned task finishes, this question doesn't really make sense.

> Not to say my consuming code would never use ConfigureAwait(false) wherever else is necessary, but it shouldn't be necessary there if I understand it correctly.

We don't know in that situation if the code running after the await needs to run in the current sync context or not.  We don't know what that code is, what the current sync context might be, and whether that code depends on that context.   If it's UI code and the context is the UI context, then it needs to run in that context.  If it's a UI context and you're doing non-UI work, then you want to *not* run in the context.

Comment: Since I obviously had the perspective of `ConfigureAwait` affecting the next level in the call stack, and your answer has very clearly helped me understand it affects the current method, can you still address if it is necessary throughout the library, or only within the method that calls something external.  i.e. the method that calls `HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync()`?  Or will the consumers be negatively affected unless every layer in my library has `ConfigureAwait`?

Comment: Or if this is correct: If, within the same method, and particularly after `await`ing an `async` call, you will be utilizing the SynchronizationContext.  Then those `await`ed calls, prior to writing back to the UI or accessing HttpContext for example, need to have their Task configured with `ConfigureAwait(false)` so that such calls do not try to marshall back to the SynchronizationContext for future code, and thus hang the `await`ed `async` call.

Comment: @Suamere You should configure the `await` to not use the current context any time the code after the `await` doesn't need to run in the current context, as the answer mentions.  Whether the code running after the `await` needs to run in the current context depends on that code, and what the context is.  Most libraries won't be doing anything with the current context, but some will (i.e. a library designed to interact with a particular UI).

Comment: You don't configure the await to not use the current context to avoid hanging.  If the program hangs it's because someone blocked when they shouldn't.  You configure the await to not use the current context to avoid the synchronization overhead when you don't actually benefit from it.  It's a minor performance improvement. (But still worth doing when appropriate in library code, generally speaking).